# How to send int value through SSE when the value changes...(Spring Boot)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jakarta-ee, server, stream

I've implemented an upload/update items via CSV for my website. I've also added a simple AtomicInteger to track the percentage of the task that has been completed. Now I want to give the front-end an option to subscribe to a stream in order to automatically receive the percentage without having to make a request.

I've found out that there is such a thing as SSE(Server Side Event) emitters. However, so far, my research hasn't shown me a simple way to send the integer value when it changes.

Most of the examples are concerning some custom objects and forceful delayed creations of those objects using Flux intervals.

Can someone help out? All I need is for the REST API to have an endpoint that will automatically send a certain integer when the value of that integer changes.

Comment: Write something that checks for changes, when changed send message. Also the fact that you have an `AtomicInteger` makes me wonder if you are keeping state in places you shouldn't be keeping state in (like in a singleton).

Comment: I'm using the AtomicInteger to keep track of the progress that is going on asynchronously(export/import via csv).

Comment: I know what you are using it for. The fact that you are using it makes me wonder about your code and you are probably keeping state in a singleton.